# proxy for couchdb on centos (rackspace) not working

Tags: apache, proxy, couchdb, centos6

I am new to the world of couchdb, and I want to setup a proxy so that I can access my couch databases from html files not served up by couch

I installed couch and I can confirm it is running on my centos6 server (rackspace) over 127.0.0.1:5984

I read that I need to run

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

but the server is giving me an error: "-bash: a2enmod: command not found"

any suggestions or can anyone help point me in the right direction? I am excited to get past this hiccup and start learning more about couch!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The a2enmod command is specific to Debian-based systems and does not exist on Red Hat-based systems such as CentOS (see https://serverfault.com/questions/56394/how-do-i-enable-apache-modules-from-the-command-line-in-redhat for a fuller explanation).

You will need to manually open the file /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and check the following lines are uncommented:

```
LoadModule proxy_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module libexec/apache2/mod_proxy_http.so
```